# Cs-cart: How to organize products sorting simultaneously by 2 params?

Tags: php, cs-cart

I need to sort products in category by 2 parameters, for example, by availability in stock (~amount) and by price, in order to display not-in-stock products on last pages, but sort all by price simultaneously. How to do it?

Comment: How does your data exist? From files, relational tables from a database, by user input? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: it's a Cs-cart engine (I included the "cs-cart" tag), and, hence, data organizing should be understood. My problem: I need to sort products output on the catalog's pages by 2 parameters simultaneously. I can to imagine sql-queries and php-code, but not understand how to make it in Cs-cart, may be it can be solved by editing core files, may be it's impossible.. help me who understands this

Comment: I don't think it is impossible, that'd be the first time something in the IT is impossible. If people say it's impossible, it means that they're incapable of doing so. But what have you looked up so far, have you tried any research, maybe on a popular search engine? StackOverflow works as follows: You try on your own until you're stuck. Then you ask the community. But as it seems to me you haven't tried that much by now (at least you didn't write about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to make it via an add-on, but you can do it by modifying the **app/functions/fn.catalog.php** file.

Find this function: fn_get_products
There is "sorting" code:

```
$sorting = db_sort($params, $sortings);
```

The sorting variable after processing looks like

```
ORDER BY products.price DESC
```

You can extend it by your code. For example:

```
if (!empty($sorting)) {
    $sorting .= ', my_field ASC';
}
```

You will get something like this

```
ORDER BY products.price DESC, my_field ASC
```